# use aysnc in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this `save_data` method which is being called on button click

```
save_recording(){ 
let formData=new FormData();
formData.append("id",id); 
const transcript_arr = [];
const confidence_arr = [];
const service_transcript=this.ServiceTranscriptData();
const service_confidence=this.ServiceConfidenceData();
  for (var i = 0; i < service_confidence.length; i++) {
  }
..
..
..
}

  async ServiceTranscriptData()
    {  
      var trans = await this.service.getTranscriptValue();
      return trans;
    }
    async ServiceConfidenceData()
    {  
      var confidence = await this.service.getConfidenceValue();
      return confidence;
    }
```

i want till `this.ServiceTranscriptData()` & `this.ServiceConfidenceData()` is not executed, rest of the code following these lines of code should not get executed. That's why i use async.

Getting error `Property length doesn't exist on type Promise <any[]>`
[image]
[image]

Any solution to resolve this issue. Thanks

> Service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare var webkitSpeechRecognition: any;


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VoiceRecognitionService {

  
  isListening = false;
  public text = '';
  public tempWords : any;
  public transcript_arr =[];
  public confidence_arr =[];
  public temp_trans ='';
  myWindow = window as any;
  recognition;
  //console.log(recognition);

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) {
    //console.log(this.recognition);
   
    //if(this.recognition)
    const SpeechRecognition = this.myWindow.SpeechRecognition || this.myWindow.webkitSpeechRecognition;

    if (SpeechRecognition != null && SpeechRecognition !== undefined) {
    this.recognition =  new webkitSpeechRecognition(); 
    }
    else
    {
    this.recognition = null;
    this.toastr.error('Warning', 'Web Speech Not Supported on this browser');
    }

   }
  getTranscriptValue()
  {
    return this.transcript_arr;
  }
  getConfidenceValue()
  {
    return this.confidence_arr;
  }
  init() {
    if(this.recognition) {
    this.recognition.continuous = true;
    this.recognition.interimResults = false;
    this.recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
    this.recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    this.startListening();
    }
 
  }
  startListening() {
    if(this.recognition) {
    this.recognition.addEventListener('result', (e:any) => {
      let last = e.results.length - 1;
      this.temp_trans = e.results[last][0].transcript; 
      let confidence = e.results[last][0].confidence; 
      this.confidence_arr.push(confidence);
      this.transcript_arr.push(this.temp_trans); 
    });
  }
  }

  start() {
    if(this.isListening==false)
    {
      this.isListening = true;
      try{
      this.recognition.start();
      }
      catch(e){

      }
      
    }
    if (this.recognition) {
    this.recognition.addEventListener('end', (condition:any) => {
      if (!this.isListening) {
        try{
       this.recognition.stop();
        }
        catch(e)
        {

        }

      } else {
        this.wordConcat();
        try{
        this.recognition.start();
        }
        catch(e)
        {

        }
      }
    });
  }
  }
  stopListening() {
    if (this.recognition) {
    this.recognition.removeEventListener('result',null);
    }
  }
  stop() {
    this.isListening = false;
    this.wordConcat();
    try{
    this.recognition.stop();
    }
    catch(e)
    {

    }
  }
  reinit()
  {  
    this.transcript_arr=[];
    this.confidence_arr=[];
    this.tempWords='';
    this.text='';
    this.temp_trans='';
  }
  wordConcat() {
    this.text = this.text + ' ' + this.tempWords + '.';
    this.tempWords = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to `await` the async calls.

Answer (score 1):

```
  async save_recording() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("id",id); 
    const transcript_arr = [];
    const confidence_arr = [];
    const service_transcript = await this.service.getTranscriptValue();
    const service_confidence = await this.service.getConfidenceValue();
    for (let i = 0; i < service_confidence.length; i++) {}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

because this two methods also returns promise `ServiceTranscriptData()` `ServiceConfidenceData()` and you need to await for them too

```
async save_recording(){ 
 ...
 const service_transcript= await this.ServiceTranscriptData();
 const service_confidence=await this.ServiceConfidenceData();
 for (var i = 0; i < service_confidence.length; i++) {
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks should i define `ServiceTranscriptData()` as async ?

Comment: what do you mean define as async ? if you are using httpClient angular and returning observable from your service you need to also ```this.service.getConfidenceValue().toPromise()```

Comment: No i'm not returning observable from my service, it's simple array that i'm returning from service

Comment: I have tried this code but sometimes i'm getting the same issue i have added screenshot the same code returns array but again it returns null in the service variable that is returned, can you please check

Comment: can you add your service code please?

Comment: I have added service file also can you please check, issue what i am facing is about the array in transcript sometimes i get the transcript as sown in image and sometimes the length is 0

Comment: If you create and Stackblitz demo it would be easy to test it

Comment: This is the demo i created previously : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eyrgqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fspeech-to-text%2Fspeech-to-text.component.ts, can you please check, i want when i click stop button it should return the updated value and rest of the code should execute after we get the data from service, but in my case sometimes array length is 1 and sometimes the same array length is 0 but the data is there in both the cases